# Tallying in nested arrays and returning the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Looking for some help with a problem as I'm very new to Javascript.

I want to write a function that tallies up feedback scores as shown in the code below. I want to take an array with nested arrays and if the score given is below 3 it should increase the `negative` property, if it's in the range 4 - 6 the `neutral` property should increase and when it's in the 7 - 10 range, it's `positive` that should increase.

I continue to simply receive in the console log

```
{positive: 0, negative: 0, neutral: 0}
```

which obviously isn't the expected output. What is wrong?

```js
function gatherFeedback(feedbackArray) {
  let result = {
    positive: 0,
    negative: 0,
    neutral: 0
  };

  if (feedbackArray > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < feedbackArray; i++) {
      if (feedbackArray[i][1] >= 7) {
        result.positive++
      } else if (feedbackArray[i][1] <= 3) {
        result.negative++
      } else if (feedbackArray[i][1] > 3 && feedbackArray < 7) {
        result.neutral++
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(gatherFeedback([
  ['feedback1', 10],
  ['feedback2', 3],
  ['feedback3', 6]
]))
```

Comment: `if (feedbackArray > 0)` doesn't make sense. This compares and array to zero. A non-empty array gets type-cast to a number (NaN, I think) and `NaN > 0` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is with this line:

```
if(feedbackArray > 0){
```

When you try to compare an array to an integer the array first gets converted into a string, which in this case yields:

```
"feedback1,10,feedback2,3,feedback3,6"
```

comparing this to `0` yields `false` (see the description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than) as to why) so your loop never runs. The same problem will apply with the next line where you have:

```
i < feedbackArray
```

It's simpler just to use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop (note you can also simplify your `if/else` structure):

```js
function gatherFeedback(feedbackArray) {
  let result = {
    positive: 0,
    negative: 0,
    neutral: 0
  };

  for (let f of feedbackArray) {
    if (f[1] >= 7) {
      result.positive++
    } else if (f[1] > 3) {
      result.neutral++
    } else {
      result.negative++
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(gatherFeedback([
  ['feedback1', 10],
  ['feedback2', 3],
  ['feedback3', 6]
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.length` array property:

```
function gatherFeedback(feedbackArray) {

  let result = {
    positive: 0,
    negative: 0,
    neutral: 0
  };

  if (feedbackArray.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < feedbackArray.length; i++) {
      if (feedbackArray[i][1] >= 7) {
        result.positive++
      } else if (feedbackArray[i][1] <= 3) {
        result.negative++
      } else if (feedbackArray[i][1] > 3 && feedbackArray < 7) {
        result.neutral++
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(gatherFeedback([
  ['feedback1', 10],
  ['feedback2', 3],
  ['feedback3', 6]
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
function gatherFeedback (feedbackArray) {
    let result = {positive: 0, negative: 0, neutral: 0};
    if(feedbackArray.length > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < feedbackArray.length; i++) {
            if(feedbackArray[i][1] >= 7) {
                result.positive++
            } else if(feedbackArray[i][1] <= 3){
                result.negative++
            } else if (feedbackArray[i][1] > 3 && feedbackArray[i][1] < 7) {
                result.neutral++
            }
        }   
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).